# ExoPlayer ConcatenatingMediaSource change source callback

Tags: android, exoplayer

I'm using `ConcatenatingMediaSource` to play many `MediaSource` seaminglessly, which is tons of fun, but I can't find a way to receive a callback when the player starts playing the next `MediaSource`.

`ExoPlayer.EventLister.onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray, TrackSelected)` gets called when the `MediaSource` changes (I can hear the new track at that point), so it seems like the right place but how can I retrieve the index of the `MediaSource` being played?

```
MediaSource[] allSources = // ...
ConcatenatingMediaSource source = new ConcatenatingMediaSource(allSources);

ExoPlayer player = // ..
player.prepare(source);

// ...

@Override
public void onTracksChanged(TrackGroupArray trackGroups, TrackSelectionArray trackSelections) {
    // Can I retrieve the index of the MediaSource currently being played here?
    // If not, where!?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

apparently the right callback is `onPositionDiscontinuity()` and the method to get the index of the current `MediaSource` being played is `ExoPlayer.getCurrentWindowIndex()`

```
@Override
public void onPositionDiscontinuity() {        
    int sourceIndex = player.getCurrentWindowIndex();
}
```

Comment: I think you should call player.getCurrentWindowIndex() at onTracksChanged(), which will give you index start of the song. At least, it will help for first song.

Comment: I tried there but it was returning the wrong index, this worked, read also  [here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2053)